# Modify audit trail in Alfresco using a custom webscript

Tags: java, alfresco

I am writing a custom Java webscript that accepts document noderef and an external username (string value) as parameters. I have auditing enabled and the audit log shows access to the document when I call the webscript. Now I wanted to know if it is possible to modify the audit trail so that when it shows the log for that particular document it also shows the name of the external user.

webscript url: [http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/node/{noderef}/user/{user}](http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/node/%7Bnoderef%7D/user/%7Buser%7D)

On calling this I get the following output in log:

```
Extracted audit data: 
    Application:    AuditApplication[ name=alfresco-access, id=1, disabledPathsId=2]
    Values:         
        /alfresco-access/transaction/sub-actions=readContent
        /alfresco-access/transaction/action=READ
        /alfresco-access/transaction/node=workspace://SpacesStore/c21db432-4ad6-4af2-8bcf-78bc89724afe
        /alfresco-access/transaction/type=cm:content
        /alfresco-access/transaction/path=/app:company_home/app:shared/cm:audit-services-context.xml
        /alfresco-access/transaction/user=admin

    New Data: 
        /alfresco-access/transaction/sub-actions=readContent
        /alfresco-access/transaction/action=READ
        /alfresco-access/transaction/type=cm:content
        /alfresco-access/transaction/user=admin
        /alfresco-access/transaction/path=/app:company_home/app:shared/cm:audit-services-context.xml
```

I want to store the {user} also in the audit trail.

Comment: Share your code trials

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/audit-cust.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `AuthenticationUtil.setFullyAuthenticatedUser`. I think this should help you. But I didn't test this.

Comment: I'm not fan of that method, I would rather use AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem() instead!

Comment: @YounesRegaieg And how this is should work? Rohit wants to store user(from url path) in audit.

Comment: @mrgrechkinn I actually tend to recommend not to use `AuthenticationUtil.setFullyAuthenticatedUser` since it could generate a lot of errors and I tend to recommend using `AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem()` When you need to executesnippets as Admin... Having cleared that thought, I actually havent read the original question when I first put my comment .. my comment was just destined to express my position from the function call you stated; Now that I have done so, I will give my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to do that, at least not in the way you describe, not without making extra security precautions.

This goes IMHO opinion against security standards, if admin needs to read a document,the operation needs to be logged with his username, if a normal user needs to access a document, he needs to be properly authenticated for that operation.

Judging from the little context I have I would say this is actually an integration with some other app that does not share SSO with Alfresco. So I would recommend a solution of the following :

- Use proper SSO between Alfresco and your application, have the concerned user ping the right endpoint in Alfresco and let SSO authenticate the request properly for you.
- Use a shared secret (something like a shared passphrase to encode encode the authority name in the request + proper authentication subsystem or request filter to handle that) or a key pair (something like securecomms between solr and alfresco) to be able to securely pass on authority information to the request
- Use a system account (preferably not admin, but one that is dedicated to this usecase/application integration) to generate a valid alf_ticket for the user in question, and have your app attach that ticket to the request. (Of course, your "impersonate" webscript would need to check for the right system/integration username, before running the snippet to get the alf_ticket from a runAsSystem block). In this case, I would also recommend not using the admin account for this but rather use a user with no permissions at all except for this usecase.

If you are going to opt for the quick implementation that you have, I would recommend at least the following :

- You need to make sure that not any user can ping that webscript and that only admin/system user can actually access that webscript.
- You probably should log the whole impersonation operation in the audit trail (either using the same audit entry or a separate one), so that it would be clear that this is actually an operation that was made on behalf of the user and not directly by the user himself
- If you use the webscript in question for anything other than reading the content of the node (Can be the case also if you have a onReadContent behaviour that has some nasty `AuthenticationUtil.setFullyAuthenticatedUser` as well), and you require that operation to be logged as system/originally authenticated user, You will probably have a hard time doing that... and you should switch to a more robust approach!